# Disable firefox fullscreen warning with html5 stuff?

Tags: firefox, fullscreen, html5

Whenever I go fullscreen in html5 things it puts a message at the top saying you're now in fullscreen, the problem is that this message totally stops you being able to do anything else until it disapears.  So if I open a youtube video in fullscreen I can't pause it or do anything until I wait for the message to disapear.  How can I disable the message totally?

Comment: For Firefox version 43 onward the options are changed (refer to my comment below)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is the security feature, but yes it's annoying if you're on trusted site and the message popups every time you enter full screen.

Solution: enter **about:config** in address-bar, and search for **full-screen-api.approval-required** and set it to **false**

You're done!

Comment: Removed the annoying warning without so much as a restart. @Lost you may want to accept this answer.

Comment: It would appear that the OP's username has become prophecy.

Comment: I think this feature is very annoying, so I disabled it, thanks for the tip

Comment: `full-screen-api.approval-required` preference no longer exists.

Comment: Sorry for accepting the answer late. It only took me 4 years 7 months.

Answer (score 13):

***UPDATE*: OCT-2019 to cover Firefox Quantum**:

Enter **about:config** in Firefox address-bar and search for the keyword "full-screen". Identify following listing and change their respective values as mentioned against them below:

```
full-screen-api.transition-duration.enter - 0 0
full-screen-api.transition-duration.leave - 0 0
full-screen-api.transition.timeout - 0
full-screen-api.warning.delay - 0
full-screen-api.warning.timeout - 0
```

*(Archival Notes)* **FireFox 42**

Option "**full-screen-api.approval-required**", no longer hides the **Website is Now Full Screen** warning. In previous versions setting it to "false" could resolve the problem. They are putting a new option in i.e. (**full-screen-api.warning.timeout** *"0"*) that will do the same thing, but it will be rolled out in **FireFox 43**.

You can change the fade in/out animation when going full-screen by setting:

> full-screen-api.transition-duration.enter 0 0
>
> full-screen-api.transition-duration.leave 0 0

**Note/Warning** - Defaults are *200 200* and *0 0* will remove them completely.

Keep in mind these are put in because they are a security features to help stop Phishing Attacks. So either wait till Firefox should enable "***full-screen-api.warning.timeout***" option in next few releases OR use above at your own risk...

Comment: More information > [support.mozilla.org](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1085113)

Comment: Another link > [support.mozilla.org](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1092553)

Comment: Creating a userChrome.css file, was the only method that worked for me - all others failed.

Comment: Didn't work for me

Comment: I'm getting tired to track these kind of config changes… they happen more and more often.

Comment: Firefox 43 is Out and setting "full-screen-api.warning.timeout" to 0 (ZERO) is working well.. Try it out!!!

Comment: Thanks for this, the answer above should reflect this change too, since it's basically useless now.

Comment: Doesn't work, both `full-screen-api.transition-duration.enter` and `full-screen-api.transition-duration.leave` are set to `0 0`. `full-screen-api.warning.timeout` to `0` does work in Firefox 55.

Comment: Here in 2019, I think the functionality has changed.  I still see the notification, and under certain conditions, it stays on top of the video full screen, which is distracting.

Comment: @YetAnotherRandomUser, I've made changes to my answer to reflect with Firefox Quantum. Hope it helps..

Answer (score 1):

Since **Firefox 43** (still working in **59**)

1) enter `about:config` in address-bar

2) set `full-screen-api.warning.timeout` to `0`